# binding two tables with expss like output

Tags: r

I am trying to bind two tables in expss , if num == TRUE then  return(list(df1, df2))  should be single table bind one by another with one blank row between them.

also the format should also be the same EXPSS like output

```
library(expss)
mtcars = apply_labels(mtcars,
                      mpg = "Miles/(US) gallon",
                      cyl = "Number of cylinders",
                      disp = "Displacement (cu.in.)",
                      hp = "Gross horsepower",
                      drat = "Rear axle ratio",
                      wt = "Weight (1000 lbs)",
                      qsec = "1/4 mile time",
                      vs = "Engine",
                      vs = c("V-engine" = 0,
                             "Straight engine" = 1),
                      am = "Transmission",
                      am = c("Automatic" = 0,
                             "Manual"=1),
                      gear = "Number of forward gears",
                      carb = "Number of carburetors"
)


banner <-  with(mtcars,list(total(), am))

var <- "mpg"
data = mtcars


func1 <- function(data,var,banner,num){

if (num==TRUE) {
 
df1 <- expss::cro_cpct(data[[var]],banner)
df2 <- cross_fun(data,
          data[[var]],
          col_vars = banner,
          row_vars = vs,
          fun = combine_functions(Mean = mean,
                                  'Std. dev.' = sd,
                                  'Valid N' = valid_n))
      return(list(df1, df2))
}else{
  df1 <- expss::cro_cpct(data[[var]],banner)
  df1
             }


}

t1 <- func1(mtcars,"mpg",banner,num=FALSE)
```

Comment: Try `rbind(t1[[1]], "", t1[[2]])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add_rows` should works:

```
func1 <- function(data,var,banner,num){
    
    if (num==TRUE) {
        
        df1 <- expss::cro_cpct(data[[var]],banner)
        df2 <- cross_fun(data,
                         data[[var]],
                         col_vars = banner,
                         row_vars = vs,
                         fun = combine_functions(Mean = mean,
                                                 'Std. dev.' = sd,
                                                 'Valid N' = valid_n))
        res = add_rows(
            df1,
            data.frame(row_labels = ""),
            df2
        )
        return(res)
    }else{
        df1 <- expss::cro_cpct(data[[var]],banner)
        df1
    }
    
    
}
```